# How to get string of unknown length in C?

Tags: c, string

I have been trying to learn C, and was wondering: how would one get a string with an unknown length in C? I have found some results, but am not sure how to apply them.

Comment: Get from where?

Comment: C has char arrays, you should declare char array based on length of the string.

Comment: Assuming you are asking about user input - you can read char by char (or by length limited chunks) in a loop and dynamically allocate/reallocate space to store it.

Comment: Which results have you found?  How did you try to apply them?  What was the problem with applying them?  Where's the code — an MCVE ([MCVE]) — that shows the problem you're having applying what you think is the best solution?

Comment: Not sure why anyone voted this as "unclear what you're asking", it seems very clear to me

Comment: That's the one I saw. I didn't know how to apply it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with extensions to the Standard, try [POSIX `getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).

Example from documentation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    fp = fopen("/etc/motd", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(1);
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    if (ferror(fp)) {
        /* handle error */
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check this out! Thanks!